# Proof that reflexive relations over $\mathbb N$ are uncountable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove formally that the reflexive relations over $\mathbb N$ are uncountable. Is this proof correct and/or are there any formal errors? The exercise left it open whether they are countable or uncountable, so they might as well be countable.

*Proof.* Let $\phi$ be the trivial reflexive relation over $\mathbb N$, i.e. $(a,b) \in \phi$ iff $a=b \land a \in \mathbb N$ and let $X$ be any subset of $\mathcal P (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)$. Then $X \cup \phi$ is reflexive. Since $\mathcal P (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)$ is uncountable, the set $$\bigcup_{X \in\mathcal P (\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)} X \cup \phi$$ is uncountable as well.

Comment: Almost. If you had $\phi=\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$ instead, then your argument doesn't bother, does it? But the unnion in the end has only one element.

Comment: You are assuming that if $X \ne Y$ then $X\cup \phi \ne Y\cup \phi$ and that isn't necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to do a little more work, because the map $\wp(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\to\wp(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N):X\mapsto X\cup\varphi$ is not injective: $X\cup\varphi=Y\cup\varphi$ whenever $X\cap\varphi=Y\cap\varphi$. The easiest way to fix this, I think, is to define a map

$$\Phi:\wp\big((\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\setminus\varphi\big)\to\wp(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N):X\mapsto X\cup\varphi$$

and verify that $\Phi$ is injective and has an uncountable domain.

Note too that you don’t want the **union** of the sets $X\cup\varphi$: you want the **set** of those sets.

Comment: Thanks, neatly explained! Is there a symbol to denote the set of those sets or how can I refer to the set containing all sets for all different $X$?

Comment: @david: You’re welcome! I’m not sure what you’re asking here: the set of *which* sets?

Comment: You noted at the end of your answer that instead of the union $X \cup \phi$ of the sets I want the set of the sets. How can I denote this?

Comment: @david: In my answer it could be written simply $\operatorname{ran}\Phi$, but more generally it’s just $$\{X\subseteq\Bbb N\times\Bbb N:\varphi\subseteq X\}\,.$$ That is, it’s precisely the family of subsets of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ that contain the diagonal.